# Why my widget is not returning the else block?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Why im getting this error when my list is empty?

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 435 pos 16: '(value as List).isNotEmpty': 'in' filters require a non-empty [List].
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      Query.where
package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart:435
#3      _MeineFreundeState.getalldata
package:wichtigdenyady/seitenleiste/meinefreunde.dart:48
<asynchronous suspension>
```

This is my code

```
Widget getBody(BuildContext context) {
    return dataisthere == false
        ? Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()))
        : Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamed(Searchuserinmeinebeitraege.route);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0.0,
              ),
              body: RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
                color: Colors.black,
                strokeWidth: 4,
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      StreamBuilder(
                          stream: myVideos,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                }else {   if (videos > 0) {
                         
                              return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  DocumentSnapshot video =
                                      snapshot.data.docs[index];
                                  return InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      currentvideoindex = index;
                                      NavigationService.instance
                                          .navigateToRoute(MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) {
                                        return MeineFreundeVideos(
                                            video.data()['videourl'],
                                            video.data()['uid'],
                                            video.id,
                                            currentvideoindex,
                                            listofeachid);
                                      }));
                                    },
                                    child: Card(
                                      elevation: 0.0,
                                      child: ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                        clipBehavior:
                                            Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                                        child: Image.network(
                                          video.data()['previewimage'],
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                staggeredTileBuilder: (index) =>
                                   ...
                              );
                            } else {
                              return Center(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "No Videos Yet",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
```

And heres where I defined the list

```
getalldata() async {
    List listOfIds = [];
    String myID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    var idofotheruser = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('meinprofilsettings')
        .doc(myID)
        .collection('following')
        .get();
    following = idofotheruser.docs.length;
    idofotheruser.docs.forEach((element) {
      listOfIds.add(element.id);
    });
    print(listOfIds);

    myVideos = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', whereIn:listOfIds)
        .snapshots();

    var documents = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', whereIn: listOfIds)
        .get();

setState(() {
      videos = documents.docs.length;
      print(videos);
    });
```

So its loading(returning the circularprogressindicator) when the list is empty and not stopping.  When its not then it works . Hope anyone can help. If you need more information please leave a comment .ALso you need more code also please leave comment

Comment: It looks like it's invalid to pass an empty list to `whereIn`. What result do you expect `myVideos` to be when `listOfIds` is empty?

Comment: When you take a look on the getalldata method I set a int videos equal to the length of the documents . And then I checked if its bigger then 0 then show me all videos and if not im returning a text NO videos yet

Comment: I updated also my code maybe its not better to understand

Comment: Thanks. But that's not an answer to my question. The error you get is `'in' filters require a non-empty [List]`, since your `listOfIds` is empty. What do you want `myVideos` and/or `documents` to be when the list is empty?

Comment: im not getting it . So when thr list is empty that means no videos exist because i follow no user . And in that case i wanna show no videos so the stream myvideos should be display nothing . When i again follow a user the problem should be away becausr the listofids will not be empty anymore no matter if  that user that i follow has  videos uploaded or not

Comment: if you mean i have to display something then thats propably not the corret solution for me . In that case is there other way to get the data ?

Comment: `if (listOfIds.isEmpty) { myVideos = []  } else {myVideos = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', whereIn:listOfIds)
        .snapshots(); }`?

Comment: it says A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Stream<dynamic>'.

Comment: oh dude i solved it thanks Puff . I just use that instead myVideos = Stream.empty(); maybe you can also now help with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67397938/how-to-get-each-document-from-firebase again thanks

Comment: Ok when tapping then on the video im again getting that error 'in' filters require a non-empty [List]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uid` field is not an array, but you're using `arrayContains` to query it. That won't work. If you want to check if a single-value field has one of many values, use the [`in` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any):

```
.where('uid', whereIn: listOfIds)
```

Comment: Hey frank I was using that but I had 2 problems the fist one was that the when the listofids was empty It was only loading. And the other problem was that with the max of 10 I cannot figure out how to solve that in my case would you maybe take a look on that problem when I updating the question and the post ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that first part. Your `arrayContains` won't work because the `uid` field is not an array. Regardless of what else was going wrong, you will need to use `whereIn` to check the value of the `uid` field against `listOfIds`.

Comment: Sorry maybe you understand it wrong lets just solve the first one  when I using wherein and the list is empty its not giving the else (default text). Its only loading and never stop . When the listofids is not empty then it works.

Comment: I updated the question so you can maybe check out

Comment: When you take a look on the getalldata method I set a int videos equal to the length of the documents . And then I checked if its bigger then 0 then show me all videos and if not im returning a text NO videos yet

Comment: Do you have Any solutions?

Comment: I left a comment on your updated question.